# How to find function calls in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida

I'm analyzing some *.DLL, I found a function such as sub_10151561 () and I would like to know which other functions call this function.
How to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the "xrefs" in IDA to visualize which function is calling the function you are interested in.

Put your cursor on the function you want to trace, use the shortcut "x" (or "Jump" -> "Jump to xref to operand"), and you'll see a list of functions using the one you are interested in :)